RNG batching and reproducability: how do you generate random numbers in batches that continue the random sequence?
I am running a monte carlo simulation in R that is required to be run in batches due to memory and time constraints. I want the results to be reproducible. To do this I want to be able to save the 'random state' of the RNG at the end of each batch and then load it at the start of the next batch to continue the pseudo random sequence. I am having issues doing this, in particular the reproducability does not seem to work if I generate multiple types of random numbers (unif, norm, lognorm) within a batch.
I have provided an example of my understanding and an example of when it doesn't work:

# check session rng_state
state_0 <- .Random.seed

# changes when a seed is specified
set.seed(42)
state_1 <- .Random.seed
all.equal(state_1,state_2)

# generate random numbers
unif_1 <- runif(10)
state_2 <- .Random.seed

# random state has now changed
all.equal(state_1,state_2)
#[1] "Mean relative difference: 1.273813"

# new random numbers are generated continuing the random sequence
unif_2 <- runif(10) 
all.equal(unif_1,unif_2)
#[1] "Mean relative difference: 0.4847836"

# reset random state to regenerate the random sequence
.Random.seed <- state_1
unif_1_2 <- runif(20)
all.equal(unif_1_2, c(unif_1,unif_2))
#[1] TRUE

# i want to generate random numbers in batches and continue the random sequence 
# whilst making sure it is reproducable

generate_rn <- function(num, rng_state){
  .Random.seed <- rng_state
  
  unif <- runif(num)
  norm <- rnorm(num)
  
  random_numbers <- cbind(unif,norm)
  rng_state <- .Random.seed
  return(list(random_numbers,rng_state))
}

# call function to generate random numbers for first batch using the starting random state
batch_1 <- generate_rn(10,state_1)

# call function to generate random numbers for second batch using the ending random state from batch 1
batch_2 <- generate_rn(10,batch_1[[2]])


batch_1_2 <- generate_rn(20,state_1)

# the random state after both functions are the same as we have generated 40 random numbers in each
all.equal(batch_1_2[[2]],batch_2[[2]])
# [1] TRUE

# but the random numbers produced are not the same
all.equal(batch_1_2[[1]],rbind(batch_1[[1]],batch_2[[1]]))
# [1] "Mean relative difference: 1.639137"

# and the first 10 uniform random numbers are not the same as the first 10 uniform numbers generated
# above whilst supposedly using the same random state
all.equal(unif_1,batch_1[[1]][,1])
# [1] "Mean relative difference: 0.5737766"

EDIT: Response to jblood94's answer.
Hi, thanks for your response. This seems to solve the reproducibility aspect and is definitely cleaner. I guess I am still wondering if there is a way to continue the random sequence from batch to batch? For example if I adjust the generate _rn to just produce a single type of random number and then call it twice, once to generate 10 random numbers and once to generate two lots of 5 random numbers, the first 5 random numbers match but the second do not cause they are using a different seed rather than continuing the rng sequence from the first 5.
generate_single_rn<- function(num, seed){
  set.seed(seed)
  (runif(num))
}

nums_3 <- c(5,5)
nums_4 <- c(10)
seeds_3 <- seeds[1:2]
seeds_4 <- seeds[1]
res_3 <- Map(generate_single_rn, nums_3,seeds_3)

#> res_3
#[[1]]
#[1] 0.82047671 0.62451587 0.83677751 0.06815233 0.97957789

#[[2]]
#[1] 0.6394495 0.6867910 0.6124927 0.7527410 0.6202278

res_4 <- Map(generate_single_rn, nums_4,seeds_4)
#> res_4
#[[1]]
#[1] 0.82047671 0.62451587 0.83677751 0.06815233 0.97957789 0.07133851 0.84175755 0.79822464
#[9] 0.84784338 0.41118260

This might not be an issue because the chances of overlapping sequences is so small due to the very large period of the MT RNG even when generating very large amounts of random numbers.
Thanks again.

From ?.Random.seed:

It can be saved and restored, but should not be altered by the user.

Could you instead use set.seed like this? It would be fully reproducible.
generate_rn <- function(num, seed){
  set.seed(seed)
  cbind(runif(num), rnorm(num))
}

(seed0 <- sample(.Machine$integer.max, 1))
#> [1] 8172132
set.seed(seed0)
nBatches <- 5
seeds <- sample(.Machine$integer.max, nBatches, 1)
nums <- sample(10, 5, 1)
res_1 <- Map(generate_rn, nums, seeds)
res_2 <- Map(generate_rn, nums, seeds)
identical(res_1, res_2)
#> [1] TRUE

Then say you found an anomaly in the fourth batch. It is straightforward to rerun the code for that batch:
batch_4 <- generate_rn(nums[4], seeds[4])
identical(res_1[[4]], batch_4)
#> [1] TRUE


Update
In response to the comment, you need to restore .Random.seed in the global environment from within the function (using <<-). Demonstrating:
f <- function(n, r = NULL) {
  if (!is.null(r)) .Random.seed <<- r
  list(runif(n), .Random.seed)
}

set.seed(1)
x <- f(10)
set.seed(1)
y <- f(5)
runif(1)
#> [1] 0.8983897
z <- f(5, y[[2]])
identical(x[[1]], c(y[[1]], z[[1]]))
#> [1] TRUE
identical(x[[2]], z[[2]])
#> [1] TRUE

Compare to a local assignment (<-):
f <- function(n, r = NULL) {
  if (!is.null(r)) .Random.seed <- r
  list(runif(n), .Random.seed)
}

set.seed(1)
x <- f(10)
set.seed(1)
y <- f(5)
runif(1)
#> [1] 0.8983897
z <- f(5, y[[2]])
identical(x[[1]], c(y[[1]], z[[1]]))
#> [1] FALSE
identical(x[[2]], z[[2]])
#> [1] FALSE


Hi, thanks for your response. This seems to solve the reproducibility aspect and is definitely cleaner. I guess I am still wondering if there is a way to continue the random sequence from batch to batch? I will edit my question to explain what I mean because I am over the character limit for a comment.

See the update.

Thank you, this gives me exactly what I want. Thanks again!
